# How to change the order of the variables in an output?

Tags: output-formatting

I have this output:

> ```
> a(b + c)d + 3
> ```

But I want it to become like this:

> ```
> ad(b + c) + 3
> ```

How can I do that?

Is there a way without using `HoldForm` to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
a (b + c) d + 3 // TraditionalForm

a d (b+c)+3
```

that works for me.